# Adding another row to each loop in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, arrays, haml

I have this code snippet in my view:

```
%table
      %tr
        - images.each do |photo|
          %td
            .image
              = cl_image_tag(photo.path, size: BOTTLE_IMAGE_SIZE_FOR_AA_MANAGE_UPLOAD_PAGE)
              - if images.count > 1
                = radio_button_tag 'upload', photo.id, photo.is_primary, class: 'manage_uploads'
```

Currently if I have more than 15 images, all of them are shown on the same row. I want that if I have more than 15 images, it should display it on the new line i.e new "tr". I am unable to figure out a clean and simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
images.each_slice(15) do |photo|
%tr
  %td
...
```

Check what each_slice gives you to get the result you want.

Cheers.